# Calculate variance of $X^2$ when $X$ is a random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_x^2$

Tags: variance, random-variable, expected-value

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_x^2$.

How can I calculate mean and variance of $X^2$?

I calculated the mean like this
\begin{equation*}
  \operatorname{Var}(X) = \operatorname{E}(X^{2}) - \operatorname{E}^{2}(X) \rightarrow \operatorname{E}(X^{2}) = \sigma_{x}^2
\end{equation*}
but am stuck at the variance.

Comment: It depends on the distribution of $X$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have only the mean and variance of $X$ as 0 and $\sigma_x^2$, then there is insufficient information to calculate the variance of $X^2$, which is

$$
E[X^4] - E[X^2]^2 = E[X^4] - \sigma_x^4.
$$

- For a [normal R.V.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) $\sim N(0, \sigma_x^2)$, $E[X] = 0, E[X^2] = \sigma_x^2, E[X^4] = 3 \sigma_x^4$.
- For a [uniform R.V.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) $\sim U(-1.5 \sigma_x, 1.5 \sigma_x)$, $E[X] = 0, E[X^2] = \sigma_x^2, E[X^4] = 9 / 5 \sigma_x^4$.
- It's easy to build distributions for which this is infinite.

Comment: What exactly we should know about the distribution of $X$, to calculate the variance of the $X^2$?